# Prove the roots of $p(z)+z^n\bar{p}(\frac{1}{z})$ lie on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove the following question from "A course in complex analysis and riemann surfaces":

> Let $p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iz^u$ be a polynomial with all roots inside the (open )unit disk. Denote by $\bar{p}(z)$ the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n\bar{a_i}z^i$. Prove that the roots of $p(z)+z^n\bar{p}(\frac{1}{z})$ lie on the unit circle.

Now it's not hard to see that if $r$ is a root of $p(z)$, then $\frac{1}{\bar{r}}$ is a root of $z^n\bar{p}(\frac{1}{z})$. But that's about as far as I got. I would like a hint on how to prove this.

Comment: @user159517 yes of course. Also, I think it's true that $|p(z)|\not= |z^n\bar{p}(\frac{1}{z})|$ outside the unit circle. However, the problem is with proving this

Comment: Your issue is connected with reciprocal polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(c_i), i=1,2,...,n$ be the roots of $p(z)$, then 
$p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_iz^i=A\prod_{i=1}^n (z-c_i)$, $|c_i|<1$.

Then $$p(z)+z^n\bar{p}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=A\prod_{i=1}^n (z-c_i)+\bar{A}\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\overline{c_i}z).$$

For $z$ with $|z|>1,$ we see
$$\left|A\prod_{i=1}^n (z-c_i)\right|>\left|\bar{A}\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\overline{c_i}z)\right|
$$
since for each $i=1,2,...,n$
\begin{align}
|z-c_i|^2-|1-\overline{c_i}z|^2&=(z-c_i)\overline{(z-c_i)}-(1-\overline{c_i}z)\overline{(1-\overline{c_i}z)}\\
&=(1-|c_i|^2)(|z|^2-1)\\
&>0.
\end{align}
Thus $p(z)+z^n\bar{p}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\ne 0$ for $z$ with $|z|>1$.

For $z$ with $|z|<1$, we see 
$$\left|A\prod_{i=1}^n (z-c_i)\right|<\left|\bar{A}\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\overline{c_i}z)\right|
$$
since $|z-c_i|^2-|1-\overline{c_i}z|^2<0.$  Also $p(z)+z^n\bar{p}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\ne 0$ for $z$ with $|z|<1$.

Therefore  the roots of $p(z)+z^n \bar{p}(\frac{1}{z})$ lie on the unit circle.

Comment: I accidentally posted a duplicate question earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849239/zeros-of-a-certain-complex-polynomial-lie-on-the-unit-circle
As I worked through this answer, I noticed that instead of repeating the same argument twice as above you can also note that the roots of $p + p^*$ are symmetric about $|z|=1$ and so if no roots exist for $|z| > 1$ then also none can exist for $|z|<1$ by symmetry about the circle!